# Bootstrap dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i got bootstrap dropdown but need some change and dont know how to do this,

This is start position : [BUTTON TO OPEN LIST](http://pokit.org/get/?7d7f82096168fdb7cf55754a0fb86136.jpg)

and when i click on this button, i need this action : [Action](http://pokit.org/get/?ebf1868a097f8b7a59ab5bb9641bb1b6.jpg)

So when i click on button list will slide down, and this Add to list will change with NEW list title(button)

This is my bootstrap codee for list:

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You do know, that there is no <body> tag in your example?

Comment: this is only example

Answer (score 0):

Try with `data-placement="top"` which helps you out

[image]

[The Popover Plugin](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp)

Comment: Hmm, let's say when you click on Top, list will show in that position and slide down this title Top wil dissapear. Look my images example in question